How to detect only gamepads using hdiapi in Rust
The title sums it up... When using hidapi in Rust, it seems to detect many devices that aren't gamepads (Logitech mouse remote USB connectors for instance). How can one filter those out and only list gamepads?
The properties available in DeviceInfo are listed here: https://docs.rs/hidapi/latest/hidapi/struct.DeviceInfo.html#method.open_device. There doesn't seem to be a property that can be used directly to determine the nature of the device.
Should one list all combinations of vendor_id x product_id? There must be a better way?
(PS: gilrs would work for what I'm trying to do but it's not compatible with Win7, which I need to target; same with ggez.)
